# Jquery Unshift / Unset Array Item

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a simple button which adds the value of the button to an array, and then removes it if you click again.

```
        var inviteList = [];

        $('.invite').click(function(event) {

            if($(this).hasClass('btn-success')){
                inviteList.unshift($(this).data('client'));
                $(this).removeClass("btn-success");
                console.log('removing');
            }else{
                inviteList.push($(this).data('client'));
                $(this).addClass("btn-success");
                console.log(inviteList);
            }

        });
```

The issue is the items are not removing but they are being triggered.

**console.log**

```
[22] 
removing videos
[22, 22, 22] 
removing videos:311
[22, 22, 22, 22, 22] 
removing videos
[22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22] 
removing videos
```

Any ideas, have I got the wrong approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find the index of the item and then remove it

```
var inviteList = [];

$('.invite').click(function (event) {

    if ($(this).hasClass('btn-success')) {
        var index = inviteList.indexOf($(this).data('client'));
        inviteList.splice(index, 1);
        $(this).removeClass("btn-success");
        console.log('removing');

    } else {
        inviteList.push($(this).data('client'));
        $(this).addClass("btn-success");
        console.log(inviteList);
    }

});
```

[Array.unshift()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift)

> The unshift() method adds one or more elements to the beginning of an
>   array and returns the new length of the array.